# Как получить повторяющиеся данные из базы данных MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Я понимаю как получить повторяющиеся данные. Но с моим запросом я получаю имена и фамилии которые дублируются, а я хочу увидеть и все эти дубли типо

Иван Иванов 
Иван Иванов 
Петр Петров
Петр Петров

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.date_entered, t1.title, t3.name AS `Account name`
FROM contacts t1
LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts t2 ON t1.id=t2.contact_id
LEFT JOIN accounts t3 ON t2.account_id=t3.id
WHERE t1.created_by='1' AND t1.date_entered > '2019-08-20' AND t1.modified_user_id='1'
GROUP BY t1.last_name , t1.first_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Или что-то вроде select .... where(contacts.id in (select id from contacts group by first_name, last_name having count(*)>1))

Comment: неа, плохо выдает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нагуглил ответ и применил к своему

```
SELECT B.first_name, B.last_name, CONCAT_WS(' ', B.first_name, B.last_name) AS `First Last Name`, t3.name AS `Account name`  FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(last_name,LEFT(first_name,1)) nametag,COUNT(1) rcount
    FROM contacts WHERE contacts.created_by='1' AND contacts.date_entered > '2019-08-20' GROUP BY CONCAT(last_name,LEFT(first_name,1))
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CONCAT(last_name,LEFT(first_name,1)) nametag,
    first_name,last_name, id FROM contacts WHERE contacts.created_by='1' AND contacts.date_entered > '2019-08-20'
) B USING (nametag)
LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts t2 ON B.id=t2.contact_id
LEFT JOIN accounts t3 ON t2.account_id=t3.id
ORDER BY B.last_name
```